# Good reference for measure theory on Borel algebras of schemes

Tags: measure-theory, algebraic-geometry, schemes, borel-measures

I am looking for a good reference on measure theory on Borel algebras of schemes, preferrably one that's available online since everything is in lockdown right now.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not aware that this has ever been studied. Can you say more about why you are interested in it?

Comment: Most of the work I'm aware of (I've written/worked in this area) is done via defining a measure on the $k$-rational points a variety over a field $k$ equipped with a measure via integrating a differential form. Is this what you're after, or do you mean something else?